# Can I delete files created by others in a directory I own?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I created a directory somewhere with permissions `rwxrwxr-x` so that other users in my group can create files and directories in it.

I do need to be able to delete the contents in this "public" directory, but it seems that while I am able to remove any *files* in this directory I cannot remove and subdirectories under it.

Is there a way to remove such subdirectories owned by others under a directory owned by me?

Comment: Are the subdirectories being created with the same permission set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deleting a file (or empty directory) requires write access to the parent directory, which you have as owner.
Deleting a non-empty directory requires that you empty the directory first, which you can't do, as you don't have write access to that directory (as it was created by other users).

So you need to use `sudo` to get root access to delete those directories.

Comment: I think this points out a missing tool -- there should be some program, setuid root, that allows someone to recursively remove any directory in a directory they own. (Which should prompt for confirmation by default, include appropriate safeties, and so on.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think this is very important. `sudo` is not quite same because it allows user to delete anything

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can I upvote this 500 times? A system tool broke my home directory by putting a directory in it without adding group permissions... Let's add a feature request to... Linux?

Comment: Where is the official explanation on why is it possible to delete third-party empty directories while the same is not possible for non-empty ones?.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel It's the consequence of two independent things really. 1. Deleting a file or directory is the modification of the containing directory, not of the file/directory that you delete. So you need permission for the containing directory only (unless sticky bit is set). 2. But, regardless of permission matters, you can't delete a non-empty directory. So it has to be emptied first, and you might not have the permission for that, but that's technically a separate operation.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your account to sudoers and 'sudo rm -R' the folder.

I am not aware of a setting you can apply to do it normally.

Answer (score -1):

logically you should if the directory is yours and is writeable. However i have heard of a subdirectory that you cannot write to preventing removing the folder/deleting files.

If you like try the command `rm -f filename` or `rm -rf dir` to remove a directory.

Comment: Nope, that won't work if "dir" contains files and you don't have write permission on them. See the accepted answer for details.